# Overheating in Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: hardware

Suddenly two days ago the fan of my MacBook Pro 13" 2016 no touchbar gets louder a few minutes start up, also the part of the laptop near the bottom of the screen gets hot. It happens whether it started from complete shut down or from sleep. As I recall I didn't do anything unusual before this overheating. Any solution?

Comment: So, the fans spin up - for how long?  The bottom gets hot - how hot?  What's the ambient air temp? There's lots of missing details and we need more info before we can figure anything out.  If it's a problem that just suddenly occurred - you should contact Apple

Comment: It gets hot until I put it to sleep, but will get hotter again after turning it up. I don't how hot, I don't have a thermometer. The ambient temperature is 25 to 27 degree celcius.

Comment: "Getting hot" is subjective and not useful.  It's it warm to the touch, is it so hot you can't touch it?  Try installing a [Temp App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/temperature-gauge/id467830521?mt=12) so you can see the actual temperature.  27C is a warm/hot room - your MB may be acting normally.

Comment: Any free alternatives? It's just too hot you will feel uncomfortable to touch it for too long.

Comment: You will have to search - I personally don't use apps like this.  The one that I know of [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) that's free is no longer active.  "Too long" is not helpful.  How long is "too long"  Are we talking a few seconds or many minutes?

Comment: I am also hesitant to use too many 3rd party apps. Anyway I don't think this is a normal response for 25/27 degree for this is normal temperature during summer.

Comment: 5 seconds. Is it helpful now?

Comment: Yes.  5 seconds is actually a long time.  Your MB has thermal cutoff which will turn off the machine if it gets too hot.  if it doesn't then it's working as it should. Fans turning on is **normal**.  If this is concerning you, then you should have Apple look at it.